# How to avoid Outlook's automatic line break removal?

Tags: node.js, outlook, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send emails as part of my microservice, I received a complaint from the customer about how outlook automatically removes linebreaks from the text body.
I can't solve this by re-configuring outlook because it will have to be done on countless customers.

I looked into using the "html" key instead of the "text" key in the mailOptions object, that didn't work.

short example:

```
    const decodedInnerBody = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(innerBody, 'base64'),'iso-8859-8') 


    const request = {

        mailOptions: {

            from: from,

            to: to,

            bcc: bcc,

            cc: cc,

            subject: subject,

            text: decodedInnerBody,

            attachedZipName: attachedZipName

        },

        documents: []

    }
```

and then:

```
            this.transporter.sendMail(mailOptions).then(res => {
                logger.info(`E-mail successfuly sent from ${mailOptions.from} to ${mailOptions.to}. - ${transactionId}`, {});
                return resolve(res);
            }).catch(err => {
                logger.error(`E-mail failed to send from ${mailOptions.from} to ${mailOptions.to}. - ${transactionId}`, {});
                return reject(err);
            })
```

My email's body gets scraped from an xml file and then converted from base64 to my required encoding (iso-8859-8), it seems to retain all the linebreaks properly, but sometimes Outlook takes the liberty of removing those linebreaks.
I want to configure nodemailer so that it always keeps all the linebreaks.
Can this be done?
Alternatively, if someone knows for SURE that this cannot be done without changing Outlook's configuration then also let me know please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create messages that include both plain text and HTML MIME parts.

Comment: Does that mean to use both the text and the html keys in the object? I have no control over the message itself, should the entire message be inside both? should i split it between them somehow? thanks

Comment: You can easily turn plain text into HTML - add html, header, body tags and replace line breaks with <br>

Comment: I'm looking into this solution, will update if this works, thanks!